# Dynamic xpath for the property creation in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

My Requirement is that i have to create some property based on xpath based on chaining.

Flow is something like :

1)i am calling service1 and based on that response i am creating the property mediator (svc1_property).
 2)The call is made to service2 and the response fetched from the service2 has a list of values .

3) I need to fetch a node from the response of svc2 based on the xpath using property : svc1_property.

Config is :

expression="fn:concat("//ImageList[Level='Employee'][ImageCaption='",$ctx:EmpName,"']/IMG_Large")"
 scope="default"
 type="STRING"

EmpName is the property created on svc1

Comment: can you please attached the config file...

Answer (score 7):

Use evaluate

Example:

```
<property name="xpathexpr" expression="fn:concat('//',get-property('xpathexpression'))" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property name="xpatheval" expression="evaluate($ctx:xpathexpr)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

You can find more infomation in this [blog.](http://techthoughtsforu.blogspot.cz/2015/09/wso2-dynamic-xpath-expression-evaluation.html)

Comment: Thanks, This is worked for me. I have used following manner.               <property name="xpathexpr" expression="evaluate(fn:concat('//',get-property('xpathexpression')))" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

Answer (score 0):

The Above article shows the case where  property is being used for source . But my requirement is different. The response coming from one API will give the empname and based on that i will fetch the pics of the emp from the list                expression="**fn:concat("//ImageList[Level='Employee'][ImageCaption='",$ctx:EmpName,"']/IMG_Large")**" scope="default" type="STRING"    on execution of the above expression the reponse i am getting is      **//ImageList[Level='Employee'][ImageCaption='Timmy']/IMG_Large**  ...... if Timmy is the empname. it is just picking the variable name(Timmy in this case) and is not parsing the xpath getting created